# AWS: Sync DynamoDB insertions to ElasticSearch using DynamoDBStreams

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement where `DynamoDB` insertions need to be populated in `ElasticSearch` service in near-real-time(a couple of seconds delay is acceptable)  `DynamoDBStreams` are already enabled on my table (to make the table global). The table has a unique Partition key. And most of the queries on this table will be `INSERT`'s.

I have configured a `Lambda` on the `DynamoDBStreams` that writes the stream events to ElasticSearch. This is working fine when the number of `DynamoDB` insertions is limited. But when the traffic is high (a few hundred per sec), there observed a lot of accumulated delay for events to be populated in ElasticSearch.

As per my observation, it seems - Lambda is invoking synchronously (if lambda process time is `3sec.`, this is getting accumulated for `3N sec.s` for `N` invocations).

But I see a different explanation on AWS blog - "DynamoDB creates at least one shard per partition" and "one instance of the Lambda function is invoked per shard". As my partition key is a unique key in my dataset, `N` Lambda instances should be invoked and completed within `3sec.` but that is not happening.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: You might be getting throttled. By default the max concurrent Lambda invocations is 1000 per account.

Comment: That should not be a problem as the current load is around 250  dynamodb insertions per sec.